# Object does not get saved using CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

people

I am trying to save object using CoreData. All the code gets executed without errors, but the data doesn't get saved. Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
            as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext)

        let record = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
            as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext)

         record.setValue(newCoordinates.latitude as Double, forKey: "latitude")
         record.setValue(newCoordinates.longitude as Double, forKey: "longitude")
         record.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "createdAt")


 do {
            // Save Record

            try record.managedObjectContext!.save()


        } catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print("\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")

        }
```

Comment: When I run  print(fetchedResultsController.sections?.count) the value does not change after saving.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean your data didn't get saved.  It just means your fetchedResultsController didn't update.

Comment: Also it could mean that you have only one section.

Comment: Or that you have not set the FRC's delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some thing wrong at `try record.managedObjectContext!.save()` 
try this way may it help you

```
 let appDelegate =
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

  let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


  let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
    inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

  let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


  person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")


  do {
    try managedContext.save()
  } catch let error as NSError  {
      print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
```